Repeatedly randomize a column based on conditions
I have 9 tests with 4 levels. My aim is to shuffle both test and level orders, making sure that each sequence of 9 tests only contains once each test. And I want to repeat this several times (let's say 14 times for instance).
Here is an example of my data frame:



test
level




C
1


V
1


OB
1


OM
1


GB
1


GM
1


SA
1


SG
1


T
1


C
2


V
2


OB
2


OM
2


GB
2


GM
2


SA
2


SG
2


T
2


C
3


V
3


OB
3


OM
3


GB
3


GM
3


SA
3


SG
3


T
3


C
4


V
4


OB
4


OM
4


GB
4


GM
4


SA
4


SG
4


T
4



Here is an example of the data frame I am aiming to create:



sequence
repetition 1
repetition 2




1
C2
OB2


1
GB4
T2


1
GM1
SA2


1
OB1
V1


1
OM1
OM2


1
SA4
GM3


1
SG4
SG2


1
T4
GB4


1
V4
C1


2
C1
C4


2
GB3
GB2


2
GM4
OM3


2
OB4
SG1


2
OM3
V2


2
SA1
OB4


2
SG3
SA4


2
T2
GM2


2
V2
T1


3
C4
T3


3
GB2
C3


3
GM2
OB3


3
OB2
GM1


3
OM2
SA1


3
SA2
OM2


3
SG2
GB1


3
T1
V3


3
V1
SG4


4
C3
OM1


4
GB1
V4


4
GM3
OB1


4
OB3
C2


4
OM4
GB3


4
SA3
T4


4
SG1
SG3


4
T3
SA3


4
V3
GM4



I have tried the following, with df as my data frame (based on a previous stackoverflow answer: Shuffle rows in a dataframe based on a condition using R):
df$code<-paste(df$test,df$level)

set.seed(123)

H1 <- df %>% 
  split(f = as.factor(.$test)) %>% 
  map_dfr(~sample(.x$code)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_to = "test",
               values_to = "code")

def <- H1$code

repetition = 1

while (repetition < 15){
  tempo <- df %>% 
  split(f = as.factor(.$test)) %>% 
  map_dfr(~sample(.x$code)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(),
               names_to = "test",
               values_to = "code")
  
  def <- cbind(def, tempo$code)
  
  repetition = repetition + 1
}

def <- as.data.frame(def)

def['sequence'] <- NA
def[c(1:9), 15] = "1"
def[c(10:18), 15] = "2"
def[c(19:27), 15] = "3"
def[c(28:36), 15] = "4"

Forgetting the fact that it is probably not very elegant, this code only works partially. I do get a data frame with 15 columns. For each sequence of 9 tests, I do not have the same tests repeated, and the level order are well shuffled within and between columns. However, all columns have the same test order. Here is an example of the data frame I obtain:



sequence
repetition 1
repetition 2




1
C2
C1


1
GB4
GB4


1
GM1
GM3


1
OB1
OB2


1
OM1
OM2


1
SA4
SA2


1
SG4
SG2


1
T4
T2


1
V4
V1


2
C1
C4


2
GB3
GB2


2
GM4
GM2


2
OB4
OB4


2
OM3
OM3


2
SA1
SA4


2
SG3
SG1


2
T2
T1


2
V2
V2



What should I change in my code in order to have both the level and the test order randomized in my columns?
Thanks a lot for your help!

if you have found the desired answer, please consider accept (click the green tick) it then your question could be closed.

Using base R, we can sample the possible "repetitions" with replacement. However, there are more than 3.7e41 ways to shuffle in the way described in the question (assuming the order within a sequence matters), so the probability of getting a repetition is negligible.
setNames(
  cbind(
    rep(1:4, each = 9),
    as.data.frame(
      matrix(
        paste0(
          replicate(5*4, sample(df$test[1:9])),
          replicate(5, sample(rep(1:4, 9)))
        ), ncol = 5
      )
    )
  ),
  c("sequence", paste("repetition", 1:5))
)
#>    sequence repetition 1 repetition 2 repetition 3 repetition 4 repetition 5
#> 1         1          OB1          GB3           T1           C1           T1
#> 2         1          GB4           T2           C4          GB2          SG3
#> 3         1          OM2          OB2          SG3          OB1           V4
#> 4         1          SG4          OM4          OM2          GM1          OB4
#> 5         1           V2          SG2          OB1          SA2          GB2
#> 6         1          SA3           C3          SA2          SG3          OM3
#> 7         1           T4          SA1           V3          OM3          SA1
#> 8         1           C2          GM1          GB4           T2          GM2
#> 9         1          GM1           V3          GM2           V4           C3
#> 10        2          GM3           V1           C2          GM2          SG3
#> 11        2          OM1           T2          SG3           T3          SA1
#> 12        2          SA1          SA2          OB3          GB3          GB4
#> 13        2          GB3          OB4          GB2          OB3           T1
#> 14        2           V1          GM3          OM4          OM2          OM4
#> 15        2          OB3          GB1          GM1          SA1          GM3
#> 16        2           C2          OM3           V1           V4          OB2
#> 17        2           T1          SG3          SA1          SG2           V4
#> 18        2          SG3           C3           T1           C4           C2
#> 19        3          SG4          GM2          GM1           T3          SA2
#> 20        3          SA3          SG2           T4          GB2           V4
#> 21        3          OB3          SA2          OM3          OM3           T4
#> 22        3          GB1          GB3           V3           V4          GM1
#> 23        3           V4           T4          SG1          SA1          GB2
#> 24        3          GM1          OB1          GB4          OB4          OM1
#> 25        3           C2          OM1          SA3           C4          SG2
#> 26        3          OM2           V1          OB3          SG1           C1
#> 27        3           T4           C4           C2          GM1          OB4
#> 28        4           C4          SA1          SA2          OB1          GM3
#> 29        4          OM2          GM4           T4          GM2           T3
#> 30        4          GB2           T1           V3          SG1          SG3
#> 31        4          SG1          GB4          GB4          OM4          OM1
#> 32        4          GM4          OM4          OB4          GB3          OB3
#> 33        4          OB3          SG3          OM2           C4          GB2
#> 34        4           T2          OB4           C1          SA4           V4
#> 35        4           V3           V2          GM4           T2           C2
#> 36        4          SA4           C4          SG2           V3          SA1


Thank you for your help, unfortunately this solution does not work completely as some tests are repeated within one sequence. For instance, in the first sequence of 9 tests in  repetition 3, there are 2 times the test "OM" and 2 times the tests "SA" and "T".

Ah. That wasn't clear to me at first. See the update. Does the order within a sequence matter? E.g., for repetition 1, if you were to sort the tests within sequence 1, would that constitute a different repetition?

Maybe something like this with base R.
EDIT, now works to get no repetition of tests within each level and no repetition of test/level per repetition
set.seed(42)

cbind(sequence = df[,"level"], 
  data.frame(repetition = replicate(14, 
    as.vector(apply(sapply(unique(df$test), \(x) 
      paste0(x, sample(unique(df$level)))), 1, sample)))))

output
   sequence repetition.1 repetition.2 repetition.3 repetition.4 repetition.5
1         1          SG1          OB1           T2           T1          GM1
2         1          GM3          SG4          OM2          OM4          SA1
3         1          OB4          GM2          GM2           C1           C3
4         1           T3          OM2          GB3          GM4           V3
5         1           V2          GB2           V3          SA2           T3
6         1          OM4           C1           C4          GB4          OB4
7         1          GB4          SA3          SG3           V2          OM3
8         1          SA4           T3          OB2          SG1          GB3
9         1           C1           V4          SA4          OB4          SG2
10        2          GB2           T1           C2          GM2          GB4
11        2          OM1           V1          GB2           V3          OB2
12        2           V4          GB4          OB4           T3           V2
13        2          SA1          GM1          GM1          SA3           C1
14        2          OB3           C2           V2          OM1          GM3
15        2          SG2          SA1          SA2          OB3           T1
16        2           T2          SG3          OM3          SG4          SA2
17        2           C4          OM1           T4           C4          OM2
18        2          GM1          OB4          SG1          GB3          SG3
... etc

Data
df <- structure(list(test = c("C", "V", "OB", "OM", "GB", "GM", "SA", 
"SG", "T", "C", "V", "OB", "OM", "GB", "GM", "SA", "SG", "T", 
"C", "V", "OB", "OM", "GB", "GM", "SA", "SG", "T", "C", "V", 
"OB", "OM", "GB", "GM", "SA", "SG", "T"), level = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))


Thank you for your help, unfortunately this solution does not work completely. Levels are well shuffled, and order of test is also well shuffle across repetitions. However, within each repetition, the order of the test is the same across sequences. For instance, repetition 1 is always  C, GB, T, SA, V, OM, SG, OB and GM.

Yea, sorry, it only shuffled tests once per repetition, should work now!

Thanks, unfortunately another issue arised now. Some test/level combination are repeated within repetitions. For instance, repetition 1 has twice V4 but does not have V3.

I think I am only now beginning to get the details of what you want in the end. So all tests should be present only once per level, but also all possible combinations of test/level should be present, and only once. I have an idea, gonna post in a bit....

See edit, should work now.

Sorry if I was not clear in my explanations, but thank you very much for your time and effort, it works perfectly now!

I'm not 100% sure I understand the logic, but I think the requirement is to shuffle the tests within each level/sequence group and shuffle the levels across the entire column.
An attempt using dplyr:
Edit: 2nd mutate now changed to avoid duplicate test-level combinations per column
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(test = c("C", "V", "OB", "OM", "GB", "GM", "SA", 
                              "SG", "T", "C", "V", "OB", "OM", "GB", "GM", "SA", "SG", "T", 
                              "C", "V", "OB", "OM", "GB", "GM", "SA", "SG", "T", "C", "V", 
                              "OB", "OM", "GB", "GM", "SA", "SG", "T"), 
                     level = c(1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                               3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L)),
                row.names = c(NA, -36L),
                class = "data.frame")

for(n in 1:14) {
  n <- as.numeric(n)
  df <- df %>%
    mutate("repetition {{n}}" := sample(test, n()), .by = level) %>%
    # mutate("repetition {{n}}" := paste0(get(paste("repetition", n)), sample(level, n())))
    mutate("repetition {{n}}" := paste0(get(paste("repetition", n)), sample(unique(.$level))), .by = paste("repetition", n))

}

df <- df %>%
  select(sequence = level, starts_with("repetition"))



Thanks a lot for your help, unfortunately this solution only partially works as some repetitions have duplicate of a test/level combination (e.g., repetition 1 has twice V2).

I've updated my answer to correct this.

Probably you can use sample like below
set.seed(0)
with(
    df,
    cbind(df,
    as.data.frame(
        replicate(5, {
            u <- rep(unique(sample(test)), length.out = nrow(df))
            ave(u, u, FUN = \(x) paste0(x, sample(seq_along(x))))
        })
    ))
)

which gives
   test level  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
1     C     1 GB4 GB4  T4 GM4 GB1
2     V     1 OM2 GM4 SA4 OM1 SG2
3    OB     1  C2  V3  V1 SA1  T1
4    OM     1  V3 SG2 GM2 OB3 GM3
5    GB     1  T2 OM3  C4  V4 OB4
6    GM     1 SA2 SA1 OB3 SG1  C2
7    SA     1 OB4  T2 GB1 GB4 SA3
8    SG     1 SG2 OB1 OM3  T1  V4
9     T     1 GM3  C2 SG3  C1 OM3
10    C     2 GB2 GB2  T1 GM2 GB3
11    V     2 OM4 GM3 SA3 OM2 SG1
12   OB     2  C3  V4  V4 SA2  T3
13   OM     2  V4 SG1 GM4 OB2 GM2
14   GB     2  T4 OM2  C1  V1 OB2
15   GM     2 SA4 SA4 OB2 SG4  C3
16   SA     2 OB1  T1 GB4 GB3 SA1
17   SG     2 SG4 OB2 OM1  T4  V2
18    T     2 GM2  C3 SG4  C3 OM2
19    C     3 GB3 GB3  T3 GM3 GB4
20    V     3 OM1 GM1 SA1 OM4 SG3
21   OB     3  C4  V2  V3 SA3  T2
22   OM     3  V2 SG3 GM3 OB4 GM1
23   GB     3  T3 OM1  C3  V2 OB1
24   GM     3 SA3 SA2 OB1 SG2  C4
25   SA     3 OB3  T3 GB2 GB1 SA4
26   SG     3 SG1 OB3 OM2  T2  V3
27    T     3 GM1  C4 SG1  C2 OM4
28    C     4 GB1 GB1  T2 GM1 GB2
29    V     4 OM3 GM2 SA2 OM3 SG4
30   OB     4  C1  V1  V2 SA4  T4
31   OM     4  V1 SG4 GM1 OB1 GM4
32   GB     4  T1 OM4  C2  V3 OB3
33   GM     4 SA1 SA3 OB4 SG3  C1
34   SA     4 OB2  T4 GB3 GB2 SA2
35   SG     4 SG3 OB4 OM4  T3  V1
36    T     4 GM4  C1 SG2  C4 OM1

